# React JS memoization on list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

If I have a simple app, something like this:

```
function renderRow(company) {
return DOM.li({
        className: 'item'
    },
    company.title);
}

function renderApp(companies) {
  return DOM.ul({
        className: 'list'
    },
    companies.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.votes - b.votes;
    }).map(renderRow))
}
var appModel = getCompaniesJSON(100);
renderComponent(renderApp(appModel), document.body);
```

And I would not want to rerender every list item when a title of a company hasn't changed - is there a way of implementing a shouldComponentUpdate function for the rows(li items)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by moving the output of `renderRow` to a separate `<Row title={company.title} />` component. Then you would be able to use `shouldComponentUpdate` for each row item checking whether or not the prop `title` has changed:

In `<Row/>` component:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return nextProps.title !== this.props.title;
}
```